# unauthorized: authentication required (Failed to get dockerfile path for image...)

Tags: docker, github-actions, azure-aks, azure-container-registry, automated-deployment

I have a github workflow pipeline that builds and deploys an image to Azure Kubernetes Cluster.

The workflow runs and shows that the build and deploy is successful but when I expand the steps in the deploy build job I get this error at the level of the Deploys application sub-job

`/usr/bin/docker pull restauappacr.azurecr.io/restau-app:ea4db1550f01e9e6b34b0499bfe2b6355d39fcee`

`Error response from daemon: Head "https://restauappacr.azurecr.io/v2/restau-app/manifests/ea4db1550f01e9e6b34b0499bfe2b6355d39fcee": unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.`

`Warning: Failed to get dockerfile path for image restauappacr.azurecr.io/restau-app:ea4db1550f01e9e6b34b0499bfe2b6355d39fcee: Error: The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1`

`/usr/local/bin/kubectl get namespace/aks-workflow -o json --namespace aks-workflow`

[image]

My Django app actually runs locally and I succeeded in building its image and deploying to my azure AKS cluster of which I am able to access the application via the IP address of the load balancer service in a browser.

[image]

After deploying this app to my AKS cluster locally, I now decided to push the app to a Github repository and enable automated deployments using Azure AKS Automated Deployments such that whenever I make a commit the Github workflows job generated by Azure actually triggers and the build and deploy jobs begin to run.

[image]

[image: Build and deploy jobs]

Both jobs actually run successfully but when I expand the steps in the deploy build job to monitor the steps I notice this error and warning.

[image]

Trying to access the app from the IP address of the apps load balancer service in the browser it shows the connection has timed out.

[image]

[image]

**
YOU MIGHT FIND THIS HELPFUL**

1. MY DOCKER FILE (Dockerfile)

```
# Use the official Python image from the Docker Hub
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Make a new directory to put our code in.
RUN mkdir /code

# Change the working directory.
WORKDIR /code

# Copy to code folder
COPY . /code/

# Install the requirements.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Run the application:
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

2. MY MANIFEST FILE (restauapp.yaml)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: restau-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: restau-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: restau-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: restau-app
        image: restauappacr.azurecr.io/restau-app:v2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
        env:
        - name: DATABASE_HOST
          value: "***"
        - name: DATABASE_USER
          value: "***"
        - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
          value: "***"
        - name: DATABASE_NAME
          value: "***"
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: "app"
                    operator: In
                    values:
                    - restau-app
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: restau-app-alb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: restau-app
```

3. WORKFLOW FILE (newapp-workflow.yaml)

```
name: newapp-workflow
"on":
    push:
        branches:
            - main-v2
    workflow_dispatch: {}
env:
    ACR_RESOURCE_GROUP: project1-rg
    AZURE_CONTAINER_REGISTRY: restauappacr
    CLUSTER_NAME: newapp-cluster
    CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP: newapp-cluster_group_1687195213832
    CONTAINER_NAME: restau-app
    DEPLOYMENT_MANIFEST_PATH: |
        ./restauapp.yaml
jobs:
    buildImage:
        permissions:
            contents: read
            id-token: write
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v3
            - uses: azure/login@92a5484dfaf04ca78a94597f4f19fea633851fa2
              name: Azure login
              with:
                client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
                subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
                tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
            - name: Build and push image to ACR
              run: az acr build --image ${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}:${{ github.sha }} --registry ${{ env.AZURE_CONTAINER_REGISTRY }} -g ${{ env.ACR_RESOURCE_GROUP }} -f ./Dockerfile ./
    deploy:
        permissions:
            actions: read
            contents: read
            id-token: write
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        needs:
            - buildImage
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v3
            - uses: azure/login@92a5484dfaf04ca78a94597f4f19fea633851fa2
              name: Azure login
              with:
                client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
                subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
                tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
            - uses: azure/use-kubelogin@v1
              name: Set up kubelogin for non-interactive login
              with:
                kubelogin-version: v0.0.25
            - uses: azure/aks-set-context@v3
              name: Get K8s context
              with:
                admin: "false"
                cluster-name: ${{ env.CLUSTER_NAME }}
                resource-group: ${{ env.CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP }}
                use-kubelogin: "true"
            - uses: Azure/k8s-deploy@v4
              name: Deploys application
              with:
                action: deploy
                images: ${{ env.AZURE_CONTAINER_REGISTRY }}.azurecr.io/${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}:${{ github.sha }}
                manifests: ${{ env.DEPLOYMENT_MANIFEST_PATH }}
                namespace: newapp-workflow
```

4. PROJECT FOLDER STRUCTURE

[image]

5. ROLE ASSIGNMENTS IN MY CLUSTER

[image]

6. ROLE ASSIGNMENTS IN MY CONTAINER REGISTRY

[image]